# How are hash file names requested by a browsre

Tags: webpack, hash, build, assets

I am a beginner in web development. In a project I see that asset files are built and their names are changed - a hash string is appended to their names. I know that some bundler does this magic, but I dont understand how the browser knows their "new" names. For example if I have in the index.js file `<script src="/main.js"...>` and after build this `main.js` has turned into a `main-ad466ef6367...js`, this script tag should be changed accordingly, with the new name right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The HTML that is sent to the browser should have the correct links to the js, css and other assets. If you use [html webpack plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to generate your html it can inline the hashed links to your assets out of the box. If you only use webpack to bundle your assets you can use [manifest plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin) to generate a `manifest.json` file which will contain an object map of your assets, ie

```
{
  "main.js": "/main-4kj5h62.js",
  "style.css": "/style-k67bv2.css",
  "logo.svg": "/logo-m2vb456.svg"
}
```

you can reference this file in your server app to inline the correct links to your assets.